# How to GET the id of the post in Firebase with Vue js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I want to print the ID of the post id. I use Vue js. And I use the Realtime database.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using vuefire

`item['.key']` will work in ease

Example:

```
<li v-for="item in items"> {{item['.key']}} </li>
```

after you set the configs and set db references.

add firebase(option) in `<script>` of your Component like below

```
  firebase: {
    items: db.ref('items'),
  },
```

Comment: I got it `<div class="col-sm-12 mt-5" v-if="item['.key'] == route">` and then I checked at the docs and I try this and it worked `route: this.$route.params.id`